# Error message encountered when booting a debian VM

Tags: grub

When booting a Virtual Machine powered by a Debian 8 "Jessie" distribution, this error message appears :

`Error 24: Attempt to access block outside partition` [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoeQ0.png)

I'm quite sure that it's a GRUB problem ; GRUB don't find my boot partition which is on /dev/sda1 but i've tried to boot the system with a live CD and then, could you explain how to repair GRUB to fix my problem ?

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 1):

The [grub documentation](http://www.uruk.org/orig-grub/errors.html) for the error message `Attempt to access block outside partition` has this to say:

> This error is returned if a linear block address is outside of the disk partition. This generally happens because of a corrupt filesystem on the disk or a bug in the code handling it in GRUB (it's a great debugging tool).

The filesystem is either corrupt or grub is [attempting to boot off the wrong HD](http://jaykinzer.blogspot.de/2008/08/grub-error-24-attempt-to-access-block.html).

Check the settings in your grub `menu.lst`.